# Elegant way to obtain the "day before" on a event based table in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table such as

```
dt_utc      eventid   user  category
2021-11-01  1         1     1
2021-12-28  2         1     1
2021-12-28  3         1     1
2021-12-29  4         1     2
```

Now I want to obtain the day before per `user, category`: so for all rows unique on `(user, category, dt_utc)` I want to add the `dt_utc` we had events before. For example:

```
dt_utc      eventid   user  category  day_before
2021-11-01  1         1     1         Null
2021-12-28  2         1     1         2021-11-01
2021-12-28  3         1     1         2021-11-01
2021-12-29  4         1     2         Null
```

Now I normally would use the `lag` function, but this would make event 3 (wrongly) get `2021-12-28`. The correct strategy I know is to first query the-day-before-per-day-user-category-combination and then join this to the table. However, I was hoping there is some more elegant way to achieve it in one windowed query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without window functions like so:

```
select *, (
    select max(dt_utc)
    from t as t2
    where t2.user = t.user and t2.category = t.category and t2.dt_utc < t.dt_utc
) as day_before
from t
```

In theory you could achieve the same results using `max(dt_utc) over (partition by ... order by dt_utc groups between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)` but `groups` might not be supported in your rdbms.